# jquery - Transfer link title to a inputfield and submit

Tags: jquery, input, hyperlink, transfer

I created a "fake" tagcloud as I was requested by. The user is able to a enter tag names and a tag weights. So he could create his "wanted" tagcloud.

What I am now work on is, if someone click on one of those tags, the user should be redirected to the search page an the tag should be automaticly included in the search input field. After this the form should be automaticly submitted.

My problem is, that I dont know how to transfer the link title to the inputfield on the other page into the input field by using jQuery, or something else...

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.
when user click on tag change `document.location = search page.url?keyword=clicked tag value;`.
and on **search page ::** 
`var keyword = document.location.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];`
`$("#search keyword text input").val(keyword);`

what I am doing is when user click on tag it will redirect to search page with its value in `keyword=clicked tag value` variable.

and on search page I am fetching that value and set it search text box.
Hope this helps and code not tested yet but it works.